# Printing values from a foreach array in PHP

Tags: php

Hi below is part of a code I have in my programme.

```
      .......................... 
       foreach($_POST['delz'] as $delz)
       {
            $QR = "SELECT bname, bsku FROM brands WHERE id='$delz'";
            $rr= mysqli_query($db,$QR) or die ("SQL Error");
            $roV = mysqli_num_rows($rr);


       echo "<tr>
       <td class='sc_five'>
       $rr ";
              .........
```

When I attempt to print the values of `$rr` I get an error saying `Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xam........` Can someone tell me where have I gone wrong and how do I adjust myself?

**EDIT:**

I've got the connection as follows;

```
include ('../../connection/index.php');
```

Comment: `$rr` is a mysqli result object, use `->fetch_assoc` on it.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Fix your code before you go any further.

Comment: Also don't put your query in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($_POST['delz'] as $delz)
    {
        $delz=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$delz);
        $QR = "SELECT bname, bsku FROM brands WHERE id='$delz'";
        $rr= mysqli_query($db,$QR) or die ("SQL Error");
        $roV = mysqli_num_rows($rr);
        $r=$rr->fetch_assoc();
            foreach ($r as $rr)
                echo "<tr><td class='sc_five'>".$rr['bname']." ".$rr['bsku'];
```

Comment: Everything is prefect , but you have to also iterate `$rr->fetch_assoc()` also, because the query may contain more than 1 row. Anyways +1.

Comment: Looped through `$r`, I assumed he would select one only, as he's only starting to use it instantly after retrieving it.